# Making a sprite appear at a random y point

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to create a sprite and give it a random y position, currently some of the sprites spawn out of view or are partly cut off. Which part do I have wrong(the screen is in landscape) and viewFrame is passed into the function and is the frame of the game scene

```
 let enemyShip = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyShip")
        enemyShip.position = CGPointMake(viewFrame.maxX + enemyShip.size.height, CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(viewFrame.maxY - enemyShip.size.height)) + UInt32(enemyShip.size.height)))
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    assert(min < max)
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min
}

let x = random(
    min: enemyShip.size.width/2,
    max: self.size.width - enemyShip.size.width/2
)

let y = random(
    min: enemyShip.size.height/2,
    max: self.size.height - enemyShip.size.height/2
)

enemyShip.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

Comment: the assert fails, the max is negative

Comment: I literally copied and pasted it however I fixed it, I think one reason is because you were trying to make the x coordinate random, which is not wanted, it should spawn outside screen and then I have update move it across the screen. That part was breaking so I put back in the 
`viewFrame.maxX + enemyShip.size.height` for the x and tweaked the y and it worked

Comment: `let x = viewFrame.maxX + enemyShip.size.width
        let y = random(enemyShip.size.height*2.3, max: viewFrame.maxY - enemyShip.size.height*2.3)` 

This is what I use now and it works fine, I am not sure of a better way though besides using 2.3 times the height